# How do i take a string input, separate it by every space and put every word into a array, to then do checks on the individual words?

Tags: c++, terminal, console, console-application

Im currently trying to do a terminal application for a learning project, this is my first real c++ program. I know the basics of code, but i don't understand how this is not working.

So my program should take a input string, parse it into a array of words, and do checks on those words as shown in the bottom of the program.

Here's what i have got currently, the program is not 100% debugged since i rewrote it on my phone and had no chance to compile it...:

```
#include <iostream>  

bool isRunning; 
char* input;  

int main() {     
    isRunning = true;      

    while (isRunning) {     
        // Get input    
        std::cout << ">";   
        std::cin >> input;      

        // Separate by space    
        char* words[];  
        int ctn = 0;    
        char* word = "";  

        for (auto c : input) {      
            if (c == ' ') {                 
                words[ctn] = word;                
                ctn++;                 
                word = "";      
            } else {                
                 word = word + x;       
            }
        }   
        words[ctn] = word;  
        ctn++;      

        // Log the words    
        for (auto word : words) {       
            std::cout << word << std::endl;     
        }

        // - Command checks
        // Exit command     
        if (words[0] == "exit") {       
            isRunning = false;  
        }   

        // Say command
        if (words[0] == "say") {
            if (words[1] != null) {
                std::cout << "[Say]:" << words[1] << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error: Argument missing!" << std::endl;
            }
        }

     }  

system("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You tagged the question with C++. Use std::string with std::vector. `words[ctn] = word;` causes undefined behavior and probably an error. You didn't allocate memory for `words`. `word = word + x;` can be done with strings but not with cstrings

Answer (score 2):

You separate the input by spaces easiest using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). You populate an array using a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and you parse those words easiest with [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, input) && !input.empty())
    {
        std::stringstream ss(input);

        std::vector<std::string> words{
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
        };

        for (auto const& str : words)
            std::cout << "say " << str << "\n";
    }
}
```

The documentation links above will help you identify which #include's you need for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important you should avoid stringstream: http://quick-bench.com/cQIbLJeuY55Y08Rh6hhU29j4YIE

[image]

An alternative way to split a string is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &input) {
  std::vector<std::string> cont;
  std::size_t current, previous = 0;
  current = input.find(' ');
  while (current != std::string::npos) {
    cont.push_back(input.substr(previous, current - previous));
    previous = current + 1;
    current = input.find(' ', previous);
  }
  cont.push_back(input.substr(previous, current - previous));
  return cont;
}

int main() {
    while (true) {     
        // Get input    
        std::cout << ">";
        std::string input;   
        std::getline(std::cin, input);      
        auto words = split(input);

        // Log the words    
        for (const auto &word : words) {       
            std::cout << word << '\n';     
        }

        // - Command checks
        // Exit command     
        if (words.empty() or words[0] == "exit") {
            break;
        }   

        // Say command
        if (words[0] == "say") {
            if (words.size() > 1) {
                std::cout << "[Say]:" << words[1] << '\n';
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error: Argument missing!\n";
            }
        }
    }  

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thx, this helped a lot!